# how to search records in sql server using vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

sorry guys i am a new programmer of vb.net so i need some help. i am not familiar with sql  server, this is my code in inserting employee info. and it works fine, and my question is how to search this record using emp_id only

```
    Dim mycommand As SqlCommand
    myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=;uid=admin;pwd=;database=payroll")
    myconnection.Open()
    mycommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO employee_info([employee_id],
      [first_name],[last_name],[middle_name],[email],[telephone],
      [gender],[status],[date_birth],[hire_date],[street_add],[city],
      [state_province]) values ('" & Employee_idTextBox.Text & "','" &
      First_nameTextBox.Text & "','" & Last_nameTextBox.Text & "','" &
      Middle_nameTextBox.Text & "','" & EmailTextBox.Text & "','" &
      TelephoneTextBox.Text & "','" & GenderTextBox.Text & "','" & 
      StatusTextBox.Text & "','" & Date_birthDateTimePicker.Value.Date & 
      "','" & Hire_dateDateTimePicker.Value.Date & "','" & 
      Street_addTextBox.Text & "','" & CityTextBox.Text & "','" &
      State_provinceTextBox.Text & "')", myconnection)
    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myconnection.Close()
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM employee_info WHERE first_name = 'Little Bobby Tables'"  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Please read about [Prepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) commands.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) should be your *very first stop*. Now, without any delay. Immediately-drop everything else.

Comment: Your next stop should be [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28SQL.105%29.aspx) at MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have indicated, you should parameterize your `INSERT` to avoid SQL Injection vulnerability.

Here's how you can retrieve a newly inserted Employee record by `Employee_ID`

```
Dim dbConn as SqlConnection
Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
dbConn = New SqlConnection("server=;uid=admin;pwd=;database=payroll")
dbConn.Open()
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employee_info WHERE  employee_id = @EmployeeId", dbConn)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ EmployeeId", employeeId) 
' employeeId in above line is the variable that contains the actual id you want to retrieve

myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
' do stuff with the data in myDataReader here
' ...
' .....
myDataReader.Close()
dbConn.Close()
```

Comment: question, i want to put all the data i retrieved by this at textbox and should i also use the dataset in textbox?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Here's a nice article on Databinding in VB.Net. It shows you how to bind form controls to datasource. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164106.aspx